# I can't get my contents to display/hide one at a time

Tags: angularjs

Please I need some help on this code I am trying to use `ng-click` on my `<h4>` to display/hide the contents of `ng-repeat`. The problem is that when I click on the `<h4>`, all of the `<h4>` tags get toggled and I only want one to display at a time(just the one that's clicked).

```
  <div class="container" ng-controller='MainController'>

<div class='main'>
<h4 ng-click='clicked=!clicked'>Apetizers</h4>
<div class ='row' ng-repeat='apetizer in apetizers' ng-show='clicked'>
<div class='col-xs-8'>{{apetizer.name}}</div>
<div class='col-xs-4' id='price'>{{apetizer.price | currency}}</div>
</div>

<h4 ng-click='clicked=!clicked'>Soups</h4>
<div class ='row' ng-repeat='soup in soups' ng-show='clicked'>
<div class='col-xs-8'>{{soup.name}}</div>
<div class='col-xs-4' id='price'>{{soup.price | currency}}</div>
</div>

 <h4 ng-click='clicked=!clicked'>Rice</h4>
 <div class ='row' ng-repeat='r in rice' ng-show='clicked'>
 <div class='col-xs-8'>{{rice.name}}</div>
 <div class='col-xs-4' id='price'>{{rice.price | currency}}</div>
 </div>

 <h4 ng-click='clicked=!clicked'>Chicken</h4>
 <div class ='row' ng-repeat='chicken in chickens' ng-show='clicked'>
 <div class='col-xs-8'>{{chicken.name}}</div>
 <div class='col-xs-4' id='price'>{{chicken.price | currency}}</div>
 </div>

 <h4 ng-click='clicked=!clicked'>Seafood</h4>
 <div class ='row' ng-repeat='seafood in seafoods' ng-show='clicked'>

 <div class='col-xs-8'>{{seafood.name}}</div>
 <div class='col-xs-4' id='price'>{{seafood.price | currency}}</div>
 </div>

 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create one variable for each h4

```
<h4 ng-click='clicked=!clicked'>Apetizers</h4>
<div class ='row' ng-repeat='apetizer in apetizers' ng-show='clicked'>
<div class='col-xs-8'>{{apetizer.name}}</div>
<div class='col-xs-4' id='price'>{{apetizer.price | currency}}</div>
</div>

<h4 ng-click='clicked2=!clicked2'>Soups</h4>
<div class ='row' ng-repeat='soup in soups' ng-show='clicked2'>
<div class='col-xs-8'>{{soup.name}}</div>
<div class='col-xs-4' id='price'>{{soup.price | currency}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you validate to close your answer please.